# Unknown reason why ACS authenticating every 5 minutes

Tags: azure

We have an MVC application that uses Azure AD for authentication. We have noticed behavior that after 5 minutes, the application automatically reauthenicates (to the accesscontrol URL). Of course this causes disturbances in application uses and causes loses any ajax posts. To clarify, the token lifetime is 30 minutes, so it doesn't go to the login screen, just posts back to ACS and then back to the application.

We have not made any customizations to the application configurations, other than what was defaulted when first implemented. I have verified that the Token lifetime for each RP is 30 minutes.

We have a Azure Website and Web Role, and this is happening on both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several pieces at play here - the token lifetime is one, but the local cookie lifetime is another, and I wonder if the problem is that the local cookie expires after 5 minutes and so the token has to be re-retrieved. 
I'm not sure what the default for the cookie lifetime is, but it's worth looking into.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2010/06/16/warning-sliding-sessions-are-closer-than-they-appear.aspx) post is not exactly about your issue, but it describes the mechanisms at play so will hopefully be useful, it also shows the configuration you can try and tweak to investigate